# How can I display pixel by pixel the calculation of a circle?

Tags: animation, javafx, service

Few days before, I asked you to help me because I couldn't show the drawing of a circle pixel by pixel (the drawing got stuck). @James_D found the solution and told me it was because a background-thread was trying to modify the UI. Indeed, I have a `GraphicEngine` class that extends `Service` : this class is this background-thread and its aim was to calculate and modify the image (now its aim is just to calculate the circle's pixels).

Well, finally, thanks to @James_D, I have now some classes :

1. `GraphicEngine`,
2. `ImageAnimation` which contains the animation of drawing,
3. `DialogCreationOfCircularGradation`, which is a dialog containing a button "OK, draw circle !" and which handles this event.

The below source contains the answer of my program to the user-event "Draw a circle". It gets several `Textfield`'s input and give it to the `GraphicsEngine`. Moreover it asks the latter to do the calculation of the circle's pixels and asks the `ImageAnimation` to display the calculation pixel by pixel, during the calculation done by the `GraphicsEngine`.

**CLASS DialogCreationOfCircularGradation**

```
public void dialogHandleEvents() {
    Optional r = this.showAndWait();
    if(r.isPresent() && r.get() == ButtonType.OK) { // The user clicks on "OK, draw the circle !"
        int radius = Integer.parseInt(this.dialog_field_radius.getText());
        [...]

        this.gui.getImageLoader().loadImageFromUsersPreferences(x0 + thickness + 2*radius, y0 + thickness + 2*radius);
        this.gui.getGraphicEngine().setOperationToDo("Circle");
        this.gui.getGraphicEngine().setRadius(radius);
        [...]
        this.gui.getGraphicEngine().restart();
        this.gui.getImageAnimation().start();
    }
}
```

The below code is `GraphicsEngine`'s one. As you can see, there is in particular one important variable which is incremented during the circle algorithm : its name is `counter_max`. Why this variable is important ? Because it's necessary used in the class `ImageAnimation`. Look at its source after `GraphicsEngine`'s one.

**CLASS GraphicEngine**

```
public class GraphicEngine extends Service<Void> {
    private int image_width, image_height;
    private PixelReader pixel_reader;
    private BlockingQueue<Pixel> updates;

    private String operation_to_do;
    private int radius; [...]

    public void setOperationToDo(String operation_to_do) {
        this.operation_to_do = operation_to_do;
    }

    public Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {

            protected Void call() {
                switch(operation_to_do) {
                    [...]
                    case "Circle" :
                        traceCircularGradation();
                        break;
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
    }

private void traceCircularGradation() {
    double w = 2 * 3.141, precision = 0.001;

    long counter_max = 0;
    int x, y;
    this.gui.getImageAnimation().setMax(counter_max);
    double[] rgb_gradation;
    for (double current_thickness = 0; current_thickness <= this.thickness; current_thickness++) {
        for (double angle = 0; angle <= w; angle += precision) {
            x = (int) ((current_thickness + radius) * Math.cos(angle) + x0);
            y = (int) ((current_thickness + radius) * Math.sin(angle) + y0);
            if(x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
                counter_max++;
                rgb_gradation = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(angle, w);
                updates.add(new Pixel(x, y, Color.color(rgb_gradation[0], rgb_gradation[1], rgb_gradation[2])));
            }
        }
    }
    this.gui.getImageAnimation().setMax(counter_max);
}
```

The variable `counter_max` is used in `ImageAnimation` (its name has changed, its called : `max`). It's useful in the last `if` : `if (count >= max)`.

`max`/`counter_max` represent the number of modified pixels. I can't replace it with `image_width * image_height` because in the circle algorithm, only the circle's pixels are drawn/modified. The other pixels of the image are not.

So I have either to compute `counter_max` as I did here in the `for` loops and then give it to `ImageAnimation`, or find a mathematical formula to determine it before the `for`. In the first case, the display of the circle doesn't work.

It would be really perfect if a formula existed.

**CLASS ImageAnimation**

```
public class ImageAnimation extends AnimationTimer {
    private Gui gui;
    private long max;
    private long count, start;

    ImageAnimation (Gui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
        this.count = 0;
        this.start = -1;
    }

    public void setMax(long max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long timestamp) {
        if (start < 0) {
            start = timestamp ;
            return ;
        }

        WritableImage writable_image = this.gui.getWritableImage();
        BlockingQueue<Pixel> updates = this.gui.getUpdates();
        while (timestamp - start > (count* 5_000_000) / (writable_image.getWidth()) && ! updates.isEmpty()) {
            Pixel update = updates.remove();
            count++;
            writable_image.getPixelWriter().setColor(update.getX(), update.getY(), update.getColor());
        }

        if (count >= max) {
            this.count = 0;
            this.start = -1;
            stop();
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        this.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works because `startAnimation()` doesn't modify the UI: `handle(...)` modifies the UI. And `handle(...)` is invoked on the FX Application Thread (that's just how an `AnimationTimer` works). The documentation for [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) is really poor; it's not clear if you can call `start()` from a background thread. While this appears to work (for your particular JDK version, on your particular machine), I recommend calling `setMax(...)` and `startAnimation()` on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you. I searched on Google if an `AnimationTimer` creates its own thread, you answered somebody on Stackoverflow that it's not the case, but I didn't understand that `AnimationTimer` was always invoked on the FX App Thread. Thank you again !

Comment: All that happens is that the underlying system keeps a list of all active `AnimationTimer`s (and other animations). When each "frame" is rendered (which of course happens on the FX Application Thread), each active `AnimationTimer`'s `handle()` method is invoked as part of rendering the frame.

Comment: Ah okay. I have a last question : as you know, the main is to display pixel by pixel the photo retouching, while the algorithm is processing. You helped me with this `Animation`, and as you can see it, the `start` is executed at the end of the algorithm (so at the end of the `Task`/thread). Do you know if it makes the thread useless ? Because with this code, I think all the new pixels are calculated, and AFTER all these calculations, this same thread launches the animation. So I don't know if there is parallelism between the display and the calculation in fact ?

Comment: Correct. So start the `AnimationTimer` at the beginning, instead of the end

Comment: Arf, I can't. And that's for the same reason I can't call `setMax` and `startAnimation` in the FX App Thread. Indeed, I have to compute the variable `counter_max` in my algorithm to give it to `ImageAnimation`. To do that, I need to launch the algorithm and increment it (I didn't find the formula to calculate `counter_max`, I'm not really good in mathematics...). I must proceed like that only for the circle because I draw only some pixels, not the width*height ones. For other algorithms like reverse, I can directly say that `counter_max = width*height` and give it to `ImageAnimation`.

Comment: Do you know if I can I can replace, in `ImageAnimation`, ` if (count >= max)` with : `if(updates.size() = 0)` ?

Comment: That won't work, because it's possible (if unlikely) that you get two calls to `handle()` before the background thread has a chance to add more updates, so you could terminate the thread prematurely. But this "question" is getting a bit out of hand and just turning into a discussion, which is not the purpose of this forum. If you have a specific question, [edit] the post to make it clear what the specific question is.

Comment: Well, can I create another topic to ask for a formula to calculate `counter_max` ? If it exists, I would be abel to call `setMax` and `startAnimation` from FX App Thread, or at least `setMax` in `GraphicEngine` and `startAnimation` in FX App Thread. So it could solve my problem.

Comment: Edit this question. It's not really clear what the problem is (not to me, anyway). Just set it when you know the value.

Comment: Ok, I just have edited my question : I explained my problem and the sources. Don't hesitate to ask for more explanations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to compute `max` later, then you can't initialize it to zero (because if you do any updates before it is set to its "correct" value, then `count` will exceed `max` and you will stop the animation). So just initialize it to something it will never reach, e.g. `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Relatedly, since you are accessing `max` from multiple threads, you should either synchronize access to it, or (better) use an [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html). I.e.

```
public class ImageAnimation extends AnimationTimer {
    private Gui gui;
    private AtomicLong max;
    private long count, start;

    ImageAnimation (Gui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
        this.count = 0;
        this.start = -1;
        this.max = new AtomicLong(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public void setMax(long max) {
        this.max.set(max);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long timestamp) {
        if (start < 0) {
            start = timestamp ;
            return ;
        }

        WritableImage writable_image = this.gui.getWritableImage();
        BlockingQueue<Pixel> updates = this.gui.getUpdates();
        while (timestamp - start > (count* 5_000_000) / (writable_image.getWidth()) && ! updates.isEmpty()) {
            Pixel update = updates.remove();
            count++;
            writable_image.getPixelWriter().setColor(update.getX(), update.getY(), update.getColor());
        }

        if (count >= max.get()) {
            this.count = 0;
            this.start = -1;
            this.max.set(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            stop();
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        this.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works very well ! Do you think it's more elegant to write the instruction `imageAnimation.setMax(xxxyyy)` within `GraphicEngine` for all the photo-retouching algorithms or just for the circle one ? In the first case, some of the `max` can be computed without executing the retouching-algorithm (except circle's one obviously).

Comment: That's a design question I don't have enough information to answer. I probably wouldn't structure it like this in the first place.... Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question.

Comment: Okay, thank you :) I just have a last question. Let a big algorithm which calls, like the others, `setMax` as its last instruction. Because the algorithm very big, this `setMax` is reached after a long time and `ImageAnimation`'s `count` variable reached `max` (so `Long.MAX_VALUE`) before `setMax` was reached. So the animation stopped before the end of the algorithm. Is it correct/possible ?

Comment: Huh? How would the image animation's count reach `Long.MAX_VALUE`? It would have to process `2^63` updates from the algorithm. Apart from the fact that your algorithm would just fail because it can't count higher than that, even at one update per nanosecond that would take `10^46` years.

Comment: Yes of course, but it's possible in absolute terms no ?

Comment: How is your algorithm going to produce that many updates? If it's using a `long` to count them, by definition it can't even count higher than that. I'm beginning to think you didn't even bother to read the code I provided.

Comment: Ah yes, I just didn't think that the `GraphicEngine`'s counter's value would exceed its max capacity too, sorry...